# Angular unit tests are leaking styles

Tags: angular, jasmine

In our project we have thousands of unit tests and they become slower and slower. I did debug it and found out that the CPU time is spent mostly on the rendering.

After some more debugging I found out that in the Jasmine test page DOM there are thousands of `<style>` tags which seems to be the core of the performance issue.

I have tried it on the empty `ng new` project. What I did was just to add some style to the `AppComponent`:

**app.component.css**:

`.test {
    color: red;
}`

When I run the default unit tests (there are 3 pre-defined) using `ng test` and open the chrome console on the Jasmine test page the result is following - the style is there three times!:

[image: Style issue]

While running thousands of tests the performance suffers a lot because of thousands of `<style>` tags.

Does anybody know how to make karma/angular to cleanup after each test?

I am using angular 6.1.1 and angular/cli 6.0.1

Comment: What type of view encapsulation is `AppComponent`?

Comment: The default one, i.e.`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 4):

I think you hit the following bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31834

Adding the following line to a global afterEach really speeds up the test suite execution:

```js
window.document.querySelectorAll("style").forEach((style: HTMLStyleElement) => style.remove());
```

Comment: A better solution was actually given here: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2020/11/25/faster-ng-test/

Also I think it has been fixed starting from Angular 12.1.0: https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/12.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I have tried more brutal way and it seems it is working. I have created a sample app with 1400 same tests (it just renders `@angular/material` button and checks it).

It takes 14 minutes to run this test suite.

After adding these lines:

```
afterEach(() => {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    const styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');


    for (let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
      head.removeChild(styles[i]);
    }
});
```

It takes 80 seconds to run it.

It seems to me that Karma should handle this somehow since I bet that this is quite common problem

Comment: Doubt: should styles be removed after ruining every test case or we can utilize `afterAll()` to delete them once entire test suite is finish executing?

Comment: It should be done in afterEach since every single test case is adding the styles to the html

Answer (score 1):

The component is configured to use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which means that the `app.component.css` file should only include a `:host` style and other host selectors.

Angular will inject the `<style>` tag for the component and bind it to the *host view* at run-time. When the component is destroyed the *host* style is removed, but you've included extra selectors outside the scope of the *host*. So the browser is leaving those as is, because they were not bound to the host.

Any *extra* styles that are *global* should be included via the `style.css` file that is defined for the project.

The alternative is to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` and not use a `:host` selector.

**UPDATE:**

Angular 6 has added the `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` setting.

https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/

> This specification describes a method of combining multiple DOM trees into one hierarchy and how these trees interact with each other within a document, thus enabling better composition of the DOM.

The Angular documents provides an example of:

```
 styles: [`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
  `],
```

Try using this encapsulation mode instead. Looks like it resolves the issue you've run into.

Comment: Okay I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

When I change the stylesheet to:

```:host{
    color:red
}
```

the result is exactly the same, style do not remove from the DOM.

With the `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, if nothing changed this is not supported in all browser, right?

Comment: I have just tried the shadow dom encapsulation. Yes, it does solve the problem with unit tests but the application stops working in non-chrome browsers (tried Edge)

Comment: I have also tried `Viewencapsulation.None` but it has the same result as emulated

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for this you can use called [`trimLeftoverStyles`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-ng-dev-utils/typedoc/index.html#trimleftoverstyles), that you can get from my open source library [`s-ng-dev-utils`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-ng-dev-utils). It will only remove the styles added by your components; if you added global styles that are used in your test suite it will leave them alone. If you call it in a `beforeEach` as recommended, it will also leave your component correctly styled at the end of your test, so you can see it correctly for debugging.